# How can I rename the angular yeoman index.html file

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

is it possible to rename the index.html file in the angular yeoman generator? In other words I would like to use a different name instead of index.html

- UPDATE

To be more specific

I would like yeoman to also know of the change so that when I generate a new directive, service, controller yeoman will write it to the "Build" block. i.e.

```
        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

I'm affraid if I renamed the index.html file yeoman will not know of the name change and so my new html file will need to be manually updated with the new script tag for my directive, controller, service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. But you have to change your Gruntfile.js:

- change all occurrences of index.html to your html file
- change the server settings from:

  ```
  livereload: {
     options: {
       open: true,
       base: [
         '.tmp',
         '<%= yeoman.app %>'
       ]
     }
  }
  ```

to:

```
livereload: {
    options: {
      open: 'http://localhost:9000/yourname.html',
      base: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      ]
    }
  },
```

If you would like to use the yeoman angular generators, they will not update a file that is different from index.html, because index.html is hard coded in the generators. There is only a command line argument (`--skip-add`) that prevents that the generator touching the index.html file.

For sure. It's open source. The relevant part is in the file: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/script-base.js

```
Generator.prototype.addScriptToIndex = function (script) {
  try {
    var appPath = this.env.options.appPath;
    var fullPath = path.join(appPath, 'index.html');
    angularUtils.rewriteFile({
      file: fullPath,
      needle: '<!-- endbuild -->',
      splicable: [
        '<script src="scripts/' + script.toLowerCase().replace('\\', '/') + '.js"></script>'
      ]
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('\nUnable to find '.yellow + fullPath + '. Reference to '.yellow + script + '.js ' + 'not added.\n'.yellow);
  }
};
```

you may change the name `index.html` or provide an additional option to configure the name.

Comment: the only prob is that grunt+bower doesn't know where to write the files to anymore. Before grunt would include the file into the index.html now it doesn't do that.

Comment: @EdgarMartinez what do you mean with: "where to write the files to anymore"? which files?

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific. I updated the question, hope that will clarify.

Comment: @EdgarMartinez added a hint how to fix this:)

Comment: I'll see if I can add the feature and submit a pull request